# Can someone explain me this syntax "#define HASH_IS_REAL(h_) ((h_) >= 2)"

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I tried getting help from this http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/cpp.html. But couldn't find any example like this. This syntax is taken from `Glib/ghash.c`.

```
#define HASH_IS_REAL(h_) ((h_) >= 2)
```

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward. Just evaluates to 1 if its argument is >=2.

Comment: That just tests if `h_` is greater than or equal to 2; am I missing something? Post an example of its usage, please. Why a value greater than or equal to 2 means a "hash is real" is another question, though...

Comment: I had to understand the function g_hash_table_contains of this file https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/master/glib/ghash.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This defines a macro that takes on parameter. When the C file is compiled, the compiler runs the preprocessor and replaces the occurrences of `HASH_IS_REAL` with the rules defined by the macro.

If your code has

```
int x = 18;
if(HASH_IS_REAL(x))
{
}
```

the preprocessor changes this to

```
int x = 18;
if(((x) >= 2))
{
}
```

For more information about macros and the C preprocessor, see [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_preprocessors) and
[this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/).